# Excel - VBA | Parse range values and copy to another column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm experiencing a lot of issues with this.

What I'm trying to do is basically get Excel to parse a range cell's contents and if the content doesn't equal "OWNED", copy it to another column. I actually have no idea what to do, been experimenting with different macros I found around the internet but none of them seemed to apply for what I need and I lack the knowledge to get this done, so I would appreciate if someone lent me a hand or at least pointed me in the right direction.

So basically I'm trying to get from this

[image]

to this

[image]

and as you can see, I would need the program to not spare empty cells on the first column.

I will be very grateful to someone who can lend me a hand on this, it's been making me crazy for weeks :/

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: ADDED CODE

```
Sub Update()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Hoja1")

Dim UninstalledColumn As String
Dim UninstalledRow As Integer

UninstalledColumn = "A"
UninstalledRow = 3

Dim UninstalledCell As Range
Set UninstalledCell = UninstalledColumn & Str(UninstalledRow)

Dim WorkstationList As Range
Set WorkstationList = Range("C3:C12")



End Sub
```

Comment: If you want help with your code, you'll have to post your code.

Comment: Just added what I have so far. I'm getting an error saying object required on line 16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub Update()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Hoja1")

Dim UninstalledColumn As String
Dim UninstalledRow As Integer

UninstalledColumn = "A"
UninstalledRow = 3

'this is how you would assign a range, but you don't need that.
' Dim UninstalledCell As Range
' Set UninstalledCell = ws.Range(UninstalledColumn & UninstalledRow)

Dim WorkstationList As Range
Set WorkstationList = ws.Range("C3:C12")

For Each cel In WorkstationList
    If cel.Value <> "owned" Then
        ws.Cells(UninstalledRow, UninstalledColumn) = cel.Value
        UninstalledRow = UninstalledRow + 1
    End If
Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was just what I needed. 

Thanks again for your help!